# Building aapt from Android source on Mac 10.9 Mavericks segfaults or gives "Illegal Instruction 4" on 10.8 Mountain Lion

Tags: java, android, c++, macos, android-source

This is a pretty specific question, but I've run out of ideas and I'm hoping for some new directions.

I've downloaded the Android source from the Android Open Source Project, following the instructions here:

http://source.android.com/source/building.html

I followed all of the steps specific to Mac (case sensitive disk image, make v3.81, file descriptors set to 1024) and have set the build to be 'lunch full-eng' as suggested on the site.  I have the entire tree and with these settings I can build it and I have no problems with it on my machine.

Specifically, I have made some changes to aapt (in frameworks/base/tools/aapt) which I then clean (make clean-aapt) and then rebuild (make aapt).  It builds without a problem.  When I run aapt from the command line, it runs fine and does not crash.  I am doing all of this checkout/build on Mac 10.9 Mavericks.

Next, I sent my newly-built aapt binary to a colleague running Mac 10.8 Mountain Lion and it segfaults immediately upon execution.

I thought maybe it was my changes, so I removed everything I had added.  Clean and rebuild.  Same problem.  It is definitely not my changes.

My guess is that I need to set it to build with some compatibility flag enabled, but I'm not sure what to set or where to set it.  Does anyone have any ideas where I could look?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out, so I will post my solution here for the sake of posterity.

Between the time the AOSP was established and Mavericks was released, the location of the Mac OSX SDKs has changed.  It used to be located here:

`/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.x.sdk` where `x` is the version you want to use.

But recent changes to XCode have moved the newer SDKs (10.8 and 10.9) to within the XCode.app package, and eliminated the older ones.  However, I found and downloaded the set of prior SDKs in case I need them, from here:

http://aaronwallace.github.io/MacOSX_SDKs/

I copied them into `/Developer/SDKs`, set an environment variable called MAC_SDK_VERSION to the version I want to build, and did this:

```
mbpr15:Android awt$ export MAC_SDK_VERSION=10.6
mbpr15:Android awt$ lunch sdk-eng

============================================
PLATFORM_VERSION_CODENAME=REL
PLATFORM_VERSION=4.3.2.1.000.000
TARGET_PRODUCT=sdk
TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT=eng
TARGET_BUILD_TYPE=release
TARGET_BUILD_APPS=
TARGET_ARCH=arm
TARGET_ARCH_VARIANT=armv7-a
TARGET_CPU_VARIANT=generic
HOST_ARCH=x86
HOST_OS=darwin
HOST_OS_EXTRA=Darwin-13.0.0-x86_64-i386-64bit
HOST_BUILD_TYPE=release
BUILD_ID=OPENMASTER
OUT_DIR=out
============================================

mbpr15:Android awt$ make -j8 sdk
```

Works perfectly.  This built a custom set of the sdk tools that is compatible with older versions of Mac OSX.